# Efficient solution for grouping same values in a large dataset

Tags: java, algorithm, batch-processing, spring-batch, bigdata

At my job I was to develop and implement a solution for the following problem:

Given a dataset of 30M records extract (key, value) tuples from the particular dataset field, group them by key and value storing the number of same values for each key. Write top 5000 most frequent values for each key to a database. Each dataset row contains up to 100 (key, value) tuples in a form of serialized XML.

I came up with the solution like this (using [Spring-Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/)):

Batch job steps:

**Step 1.** Iterate over the dataset rows and extract (key, value) tuples. Upon getting some fixed number of tuples dump them on disk. Each tuple goes to a file with the name pattern '/chunk-', thus all values for a specified key are stored in one directory. Within one file values are stored sorted.

**Step 2.** Iterate over all '' directories and merge their chunk files into one grouping same values. Since the values are stored sorted, it is trivial to merge them for O(n * log k) complexity, where 'n' is the number of values in a chunk file and 'k' is the initial number of chunks.

**Step 3.** For each merged file (in other words for each key) sequentially read its values using [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) to maintain top 5000 values without loading all the values into memory. Write queue content to the database.

I spent about a week on this task, mainly because I have not worked with Spring-Batch previously and because I tried to make emphasis on scalability that requires accurate implementation of the multi-threading part.

**The problem is that my manager consider this task way too easy to spend that much time on it.**

And the question is - *do you know more efficient solution or may be less efficient that would be easier to implement? And how much time would you need to implement my solution?*

I am aware about MapReduce-like frameworks, but I can't use them because the application is supposed to be run on a simple PC with 3 cores and 1GB for Java heap.

Thank you in advance!

UPD: I think I did not stated my question clearly. Let me ask in other way:

**Given the problem and being the project manager or at least the task reviewer would you accept my solution? And how much time would you dedicate to this task?**

Comment: If you have spent a week and have not yet got any solution running, perhaps it's time to reconsider your priorities.  In my experience it is generally more important to get a simple solution going with average performance than it is to deliberate over optimal solutions.  Personally, I would start with a simple sorting-based algorithm, and would only go looking for trouble if it doesn't meet efficiency requirements.

Comment: I don't see why Mapreduce cannot be used on a simple PC with 3 cores and 1 GB of heap. Go for a simple implementation first, then based upon performance issues you see, optimize, or migrate to a different algorithm. A "seemingly slow" solution is better than no working solution at all.

Comment: The very simple solution fits in a couple of lines: while (resultSet.hasNext()) for (Tuple t : parser.parse(rs.getColumn(1)) dataSource.query('INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...'). This is it. But due to transaction-per-tuple there is a huge overhead in time.

Comment: I cannot use MapReduce because the application is supposed to be a jetty-compatible war. No more, no less. This is in-company standard. And I think it does not make sense to utilize such a powerful tool on a single PC.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this approach is faster than doing a pre-scan of the XML-file to extract all keys, and then parse the XML-file over and over for each key? You are doing a lot of file management tasks in this solution, which is definitely not for free.

As you have three Cores, you could parse three keys at the same time (as long as the file system can handle the load).

Comment: Of course I am sure. I as mentioned above there are about 30M rows. Even if we had only 10 separate keys we would had to make 30M x 10 = 300M operations only to fetch the dataset. And with roughly 100 attributes per row it would be 300M x 100 = 30G operations. I would not consider this an efficient solution. Besides XML unmarshalling is very heavy operation and the number of such should be reduced as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You solution seems reasonable and efficient, however I'd probably use SQL.

While parsing the Key/Value pairs I'd insert/update into a SQL table.
I'd then query the table for the top records.

Here's an example using only T-SQL (SQL 2008, but the concept should be workable in most any mordern rdbms)

The SQL between / START / and / END / would be the statements you need to execute in your code.

```
BEGIN
-- database table
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    k INT -- key
    , v INT -- value
    , c INT -- count
    , UNIQUE CLUSTERED (k, v)
)
-- insertion loop (for testing)
DECLARE @x INT
SET @x = 0
SET NOCOUNT OFF
WHILE (@x < 1000000)
    BEGIN
    --
    SET @x = @x + 1
    DECLARE @k INT
    DECLARE @v INT
    SET @k = CAST(RAND() * 10 as INT)
    SET @v = CAST(RAND() * 100 as INT)
    -- the INSERT / UPDATE code
    /* START this is the sql you'd run for each row */
    UPDATE @tbl SET c = c + 1 WHERE k = @k AND v = @v
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (@k, @v, 1) 
    /* END */
    --
    END
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- final select
DECLARE @topN INT
SET @topN = 50
/* START this is the sql you'd run once at the end */
SELECT 
    a.k
    , a.v 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY k ORDER BY k ASC, c DESC) [rid]
        , k
        , v
    FROM @tbl
) a
WHERE a.rid < @topN
/* END */
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Gee, it doesn't seem like much work to try the old fashioned way of just doing it in-memory.

I would try just doing it first, then if you run out of memory, try one key per run (as per @Storstamp's answer).

Answer (score 0):

If using the "simple" solution is not an option due to the size of the data, my next choice would be to use an SQL database. However, as most of these require quite much memory (and coming down to a crawl when heavily overloaded in RAM), maybe you should redirect your search into something like a NoSQL database such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) that can be quite efficient even when mostly disk-based. (Which your environment basically requires, having only 1GB of heap available).

The NoSQL database will do all the basic bookkeeping for you (storing the data, keeping track of all indexes, sorting it), and may probably do it a bit more efficient than your solution, due to the fact that all data may be sorted and indexed already when inserted, removing the extra steps of sorting the lines in the /chunk- files, merging them etc.

You will end up with a solution that is probably much easier to administrate, and it will also allow you to set up different kind of queries, instead of being optimized only for this specific case.

As a project manager I would not oppose your current solution. It is already fast and solves the problem. As an architect however, I would object due to the solution being a bit hard to maintain, and for not using proven technologies that basically does partially the same thing as you have coded on your own. It is hard to beat the tree and hash implementations of modern databases.